# Maxscript splineOps.startTrim

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript, 3ds

I'm trying to build a script for 3ds max that would allow me to trim splines automatically.

After googling for the past 4 hrs I came across the splineOps global structure.

This is what I have so far:

```
---- Kustom Trim Lines
try (closerolloutfloater MainFloater) catch()

Rollout Menu01 "Geometry Ops"
(
    button select_trims "Trim all similar"

    on select_trims pressed do
    (
        splineOps.startTrim Shape439
    )
)

MainFloater = NewRolloutFloater "Kustom TrimLines" 300 200
addRollout Menu01 MainFloater
```

When I click the button in the new rollout I get a "-- Unknown system exception"

Ultimately, I'd like to build this script to automatically trim all similar segments from the specific spline

Any pointers/ideas are greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

-- Update 05-16-2018 2:34PM CT --

After playing with it a bit more I was able to make the script select the shape enter sub level and select the trim option. Here's how that looks like:

```
---- Kustom Trim Lines
try (closerolloutfloater MainFloater) catch()

Rollout Menu01 "Geometry Ops"
(
    button select_trims "Trim all similar"

    on select_trims pressed do
    (
        select $Shape439
        subobjectlevel = 3
        splineOps.startTrim($)
    )
)

MainFloater = NewRolloutFloater "Kustom TrimLines" 300 200
addRollout Menu01 MainFloater
```

Now... How would I go about automating this?
Let's say I'd like it to trim all the small lines between each 2 parallel lines that are intersecting, or all segments that are less than a specific length (e.g <1"). Can this be done????
I'm assuming I need to detect all intersections first, break the segments and remove all that are < 1". Anyone? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This gives the length, which you can use as a criterion to trim or not.

```
curveLength $Circle001 1
```

Comment: hey, thx for taking the time, but could you be a little more specific? Sorry I'm still a complete noob at this and wouldn't know where to start when building a fuction that would recursively trim all those little segments

Answer (score 0):

The Spline Trim tool is not fully available in MaxScript, so you can only start the tool UI mode, but actual Trim operations require a mouse click.

One hack you might consider is to emulate mouse clicks in the viewport.  For example, emulate clicks on the knot points you'd like to trim, which I'll assume are the endpoints of all splines (or certain splines) in the shape.  The code below looks at each spline in the shape, and looks at each segment in the spline, to check if the length is smaller than some threshold.  If so, it emulates a mouse click on the end knot while in trim mode.  Note the viewport perspective angle matters. The script needs a clear view of the knots to be clicked, without knots overlapping each other.  It tries to perform a Zoom Extents Selected, but this is no guarantee and would probably requires artist guidance.

It certainly is a hack, and not a perfect solution.  But this type of approach might be useful in various situations.

```
-- Define the object to operate on
s = $Circle001

-- Spline segment length threshold maximum.  Segments longer than this will NOT be trimmed
cLenMax = 100.0

-- Zoom extents.  Attempts to get all vertices in clear view (not guaranteed)
bnd = nodeGetBoundingBox s (matrix3 1)
viewport.ZoomToBounds false bnd[1] bnd[2]

-- Make sure Modify Panel is open, with object selected
cui.commandPanelOpen = true
SetCommandPanelTaskMode #modify
select s

-- Enter Spline subobject with Trim tool
subobjectlevel = 3
splineOps.startTrim(s)

-- Spline manipulation
for sn = 1 to numSplines s do
(
    cn = numKnots s sn
    if( cn>1 ) do
    (
        -- Lengths of the segments.  There are (cn-1) segments for the spline
        -- List indicates relative lengths, then the absolute lengths, then the total spline length
        -- So the total number of entries is ((cn-1) + (cn-1) + 1)
        -- We're interested in the middle values for absolute lengths
        -- First one has index [cn] and last one has index [cn+cn-2]
        cLenData = getSegLengths s sn
        cLenFirst = cLenData[cn]
        cLenLast = cLenData[cn+cn-2]

        -- If segments are shorter than our threshold lengths, trim them
        -- Trim from highest index to lowest, since indices will change after each trim step
        cRemove = #()
        if cLenLast<cLenMax then append cRemove cn
        if cLenFirst<cLenMax then append cRemove 1

        -- Click the mouse on the first and last knot of each spline
        for kn in cRemove do
        (
            -- Get the location of the knot in world space
            kp = getknotpoint s sn kn
            gw.setTransform(Matrix3 1)

            -- Transform that to window space relative to the current viewport
            wp = gw.wTransPoint kp

            -- Click the mouse on that position in the window
            -- Super sketchy ... Workaround because Trim is not really available in MaxScript
            hvp = viewport.getHWnd()
            btnCode = 1 -- left button
            posCode = (wp.x) + (65536*wp.y) -- packed x and y position
            windows.sendMessage hvp 0x0201 btnCode posCode      -- Send WM_LBUTTONDOWN
            windows.sendMessage hvp 0x0202 btnCode posCode      -- Send WM_LBUTTONUP
        )
    )
)

deselect s
```

Comment: Hey Mike, first off, thx for your time and dedication to dumb it down for me as much as possible... I should've mentioned from the beginning, I'm using Max 2014, I believe getHWnd was added in 2015 and up... is there a similar action that could work for '14??? again, thank you for your time.